# how remove zoom feature from android mpchart library?

Tags: android, bar-chart

I want to remove the zoom from a barchart item.
[image: MpChart BarItem chart before scroll] 
[image: MpChart BarItem chart after scroll]

When user scroll the bar chart item the y legend value overrides the x legend values or the y legend values are displayed below the X ax.

Here the code for the bar chart item:

```
  import ro.charttest.R;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.graphics.Typeface;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;

  import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
  import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ChartData;
  import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;
  import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Legend;
  import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.XLabels;
  import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Legend.LegendPosition;
  import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.XLabels.XLabelPosition;
  import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.YLabels;
  import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.YLabels.YLabelPosition;

  public class BarChartItem extends ChartItem {

private ColorTemplate mCt;
private Typeface mTf;

public BarChartItem(ChartData cd, Context c) {
    super(cd);        
    mCt = new ColorTemplate();
    mCt.addDataSetColors(new int[]{ R.color.colorful_1}, c);
    mCt.addDataSetColors(new int[]{ R.color.greens_2}, c);
    mTf = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "tahoma.ttf");        
}

@Override
public int getItemType() {
    return TYPE_BARCHART;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, Context c) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item_barchart, null);
        holder.chart = (BarChart) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chart);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // apply styling
   //  holder.chart.setYLabelCount(10);
    holder.chart.setColorTemplate(mCt);
    holder.chart.setBarSpace(30);
    holder.chart.setStartAtZero(false);

    holder.chart.setScrollContainer(false);


    holder.chart.setYLabelTypeface(mTf);
    holder.chart.setXLabelTypeface(mTf);
    holder.chart.setValueTypeface(mTf);
    holder.chart.setDescription("");
    holder.chart.setDrawVerticalGrid(false);
    holder.chart.setDrawYLabels(true);
    holder.chart.setDrawYValues(true);
    holder.chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    holder.chart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(10);
    // sets the number of digits for values inside the chart
    holder.chart.setValueDigits(0);

    // disable 3D
    holder.chart.set3DEnabled(false);
   // holder.chart.setYLabelCount(10);
    holder.chart.setAutoFinish(true);
    // scaling can now only be done on x- and y-axis separately
    holder.chart.setPinchZoom(true);        

    XLabels xl = holder.chart.getXLabels();
    xl.setCenterXLabelText(true);
    xl.setPosition(XLabelPosition.BOTTOM);

    // set data
    holder.chart.setData(mChartData);

    // do not forget to refresh the chart
    holder.chart.invalidate();

    holder.chart.cancelLongPress();

    holder.chart.setYRange(0,  1.5f*holder.chart.getYMax(), false);

    YLabels yLabels = holder.chart.getYLabels();
    yLabels.mDecimals = 0;
    yLabels.setPosition(YLabelPosition.LEFT);

    XLabels xLabels = holder.chart.getXLabels();
    xLabels.setPosition(XLabelPosition.BOTTOM);

    Legend l = holder.chart.getLegend();
    l.setPosition(LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_LEFT);
    l.setOffsetBottom(50f);
    l.setTypeface(mTf);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    BarChart chart;
}
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I added the following line:

```
holder.chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
```

and zoom feature was removed and also all possible touch-interactions with the chart. See [reference](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart).

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
        chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
        chart.setPinchZoom(false);
        chart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable all zooming in Chart.

```
chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
```